# How can I set different wallpaper for dual monitor in win10 with batch file

Tags: windows-10, multiple-monitors, batch-file, desktop-customization

I have dual monitors, and I want to set different wallpapers for each monitor. Bing wallpaper always change both of them, so I wonder how to write a .bat to **update wallpaper for my monitor 2** and **do nothing to my monitor 1**.

Comment: You should use a single image which is sized according to the combined size+positions of all displays, as described [here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/1540337/how-to-set-multiple-desktop-backgrounds-dual-monitor) and the duplicate it mentions.

Answer (score 1):

With a bit of persistence, you can achieve it like this:

Inside the registry, in the `HKEY_CURRENT_USER\Control Panel\Desktop` key, there is the "WallPaper" value, that points to an image file, or in a case of multiple images, to this file:

```
C:\Users\root\AppData\Roaming\Microsoft\Windows\Themes\TranscodedWallpaper
```

In my case, I have 2 monitors, and 2 pictures. The wallpapers are saved as files, names Transcoded_000 and Transcoded_001 under the same directory.

I don't know how you could "transcode" images into these files, but you could always manually change the desktop picture, and save the transcoded files.

When you want to change one of the pictures only, you could copy the pre-transcoded file there, overwrite the old one, and restart the explorer.exe for the changes to take effect:

```
xcopy MyTranscodedBackgroundPicture C:\Users\root\AppData\Roaming\Microsoft\Windows\Themes\Transcoded_001 /Y
taskkill /im explorer.exe /f
start explorer.exe
```

Comment: Thank you, that's a great idea. Unfortunately, I'm in a quite low level. It's hard for me to figure it out what "transcode" doing.

Comment: You don't really have to, if you can change the desktop pictures manually and then save the generated transcoded files :)